# How to send data from component to component?

Tags: angular

I have written the component that display tabs: `<tab>{{content}}</tab`

This component is included in main `AppComponent` in template.

I declarated an object in `AppComponent`. How to send it to component `Tab`, that object will be available in Tab component?

I tried to use `@Input` in `AppComponent`, but was confused in this way.

```
@Input() object: TabContent;
```

Comment: Seem I need to add @input in children component `Tab`, because it should take object from parent AppComponent?

Comment: yes, https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the input you can use template variable to interact with child components

### Template Reference Variable

Template Reference Variable allow you to specify a variable name on a component and you can access any public property or methods on that component using that variable.

For example a **ProductCardComponent** , which is the child component placed in a **ProductListComponent**(ParentComponent) to list some products like below.

**ProductListComponent.html**

```
<div>
    <h1>Product Gallery</h1>
    <hr/>
     <product-card #productReference></product-card>

</div>
```

You can see I have added a template reference variable named **#productReference** on this child Component.

Let's add a property and a method inside the **ProductCardComponent** and access the same from the parent component  by using the template reference variable.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'
@Component({
    selector: 'product-card',
    templateUrl: "app/products/ProductCard.Component.html",
    styles:[`.pad-left{margin-left:10px}
             .well-div{color:blue}`]
})

export class ProductCardComponent {

    someProperty:string="Property from Child Component";

    logSomething(){
        console.log("Method from Child Component");
    }

}
```

Accessing the properties and method from **ProductListComponent.html**

```
<div>
    <h1>Product Gallery</h1>
    <hr/>
     <product-card #productReference></product-card>

   <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="productReference.logSomething()" >Log Something from Child</button>

   <h3>{{productReference.someProperty}}</h3>

</div>
```

### Other ways in Angular to interact with the component

- @Input (Communicate with Child Component)
- @Output(Communicate with Parent Component)
- Template Reference (Another alternative to interact with child component using a template reference variable)
- AngularService

Offical Documentation :https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: @jonrsharpe I removed the link. Actually it was my personal blog link. Could you please revert back down vote?

Comment: I have no problem with links, to your blog or otherwise, that *support* the answer, the problem is that you don't show how any of these techniques might actually be used by the OP to solve their problem. As it stands, this is no more than a comment.

Comment: @jonrsharpe hmm..Understand. Official documentation is simply explain the techniques to understand OP issue. So I thought just let him about template variable as an alternative.

Comment: But you don't actually say *what they should do*. Evidently they're aware of inputs, they show them in the Q, but they don't know *how to use them* and this A adds nothing to that. Point them at the docs, sure, they should be using them as part of their research before asking, but that befits a comment (which **someone already made**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338047/how-to-send-data-from-component-to-component/45338251?noredirect=1#comment77638201_45338047), not an answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok..got it..Thanks. I will update by adding more information

Comment: @jonrsharpe Updated the answer by adding code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Using `@Input()` seems like what you want to do.

In your `tab` component, you should have
`@Input() object : TabContent`

then, in your AppComponent, you will have some variable
`var myObject : TabContent`

The `@Input()` decorator marks that fields as a target for a binding.

Then, you should bind the object in your AppComponent to the `@Input()` in your tab components like so (in the template):
`<tab [object]="myObject"></tab`

Read about Component Interaction here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction.  The docs are super helpful.